# If I have fixed size data, should I go for array and arraylist?

Tags: java

Suppose I have 10 integers. Now, as I know the size of data which one should i use array or `ArrayList` and why?

---

```
ArrayList<?> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: if you can you should use an array, because its faster.

Comment: If it is local to a function and you cannot benefit of any functionality offered by the `List` interface, I don't see any reason to use an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Is this question too broad? It doesn't really specify what the concerns are to evaluate. Ex. Is space efficiency a concern? Is time efficiency a concern? Is interface ergonomics for reading and writing the code a concern? Or is the point that this question is trying to solicit answers that compare the two options in terms of every possible concern?

Answer (score 4):

For a fixed size data, the most simple data structure is an array. `ArrayList` wouldn't take much more memory, though, as it is backed by an array (and the default initial capacity of an `ArrayList` is 10, so in your case the sizes of the arrays being used in both cases would be the same).

An advantage to using arrays is that they can hold primitives, while `ArrayList` can only hold reference types.
An `int[]` is more efficient than `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Comment: This is just, to put it mildly, a poor suggestion you're implying. Sure, you saved a tiny bit of memory - but in return, you lose compatibility with methods taking `List`s/`Collection`s, and lose access to all the built in methods in the `List` class (and yes, I'm completely aware `Arrays` exists, but it has SIGNIFICANTLY less functionality than `List`, `Collection`, and `Collections`).

Comment: @KrustytheClown If you need to store a fixed number of elements, you don't need most of the methods of the List/Collection interfaces, and it might even be an error to call add/remove for that List/Collection. Using an array makes your intention for the data to be fixed-size clear to anyone who looks at your code. As an alternative, you can use `Arrays.asList()` to get a fixed-size `List`, but that will only cause invalid calls to add/remove to fail during runtime with an exception.  You should prefer to use the type that best fits your desired functionality.

Comment: In theory an `ImmutableList` would be a better fit here, but OP is asking about arrays vs. `ArrayList` specifically. Plus, I personally think `ImmutableList`s are kind of a pain to deal with since as you said, calling add or remove throws `UnsupportedOperationException`

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` fits your need. It is fast.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
```

Answer (score -1):

**Arrays** are much faster because `array[10]` is *faster* to access than `array.get(10)`, as the latter internally does the same call, but adds the overhead for the function call plus additional checks.

So for a known limited size you will always opt for **Arrays** over **ArrayList**

Comment: This is, to put it mildly, wrong. What if I want to create sub-lists from my collection? What if I need to pass my collection to a method that takes a `Collection`/`List` ? What if I want to check if an element exists in the array - do you really want to rewrite `.contains()` every time? By the way, I'm accounting for the `Arrays` class's static methods as well, despite how inconvenient they are.

Answer (score -1):

Array always take lesser memory than Arraylist. 
If you are only going to store integers, Array list is the best option.

Answer (score -2):

I'm just gonna go out on a limb here and say it: **it really doesn't matter**. `ArrayList`'s overhead and performance difference is so minuscule it won't be noticeable in 99% of cases (And if it really matters in that other "1%", you shouldn't be using a language with a garbage collector in the first place!)

Not to mention `ArrayList` is a `List` implementation; any method taking a `List` can take an `ArrayList` without conversion.